# Do I have to change my AWS VPC settings if client's VPN is updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a situation where I was informed that an organization I'm working with will be undergoing VPN changes and updates. I have AWS VPC set up in conjunction with a Lambda function to poll their server (they accept an IP address from the addresses defined in the VPC) and fetch data from it. Do I have to make any changes to my VPC settings? I don't particularly see any settings like encryption and so on on the VPC side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused; the VPC settings have nothing to do with the VPN that was set-up with the client. The VPN applies to base-station settings. The AWS stuff just reached out to their server thru a certain set of IP addresses which were whitelisted by that server.